# GNOME Terminal Titlebar Always Black

Tags: command-line, gnome, themes, gnome-terminal, titlebar

In GNOME, my Terminal's titlebar is always black, even when I use a light shell theme. Everything in GNOME has a white titlebar except for Terminal. I also tried using another theme, and it does this for every theme I try. I'm guessing it's because the GNOME developers expect that the terminal background is going to be black, so they make the titlebar black.

**Terminal Titlebar:**

[image]

**Other Titlebar:**

[image]

See how the terminal's titlebar is always black?

Is there a way to make the titlebar the same as the rest of the system theme, like with `dconf-editor` or something?

Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: In the second photo, it appears this window is simply not using a title bar.

Comment: Go to `terminal` Preferences/General and change the Theme variant.

Comment: @mchid nautilus still uses a titlebar, just a marged version of it. I updated my question with a better example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While changing this via `dconf-editor` certainly is an option, it can be done easier: the setting is exposed in the user interface.

In Gnome Terminal, open the Preferences. On the tab "General" under "Global", change the "Theme variant" to "Light".

Comment: Wow, I feel stupid for going into dconf editor while it was right under my nose. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 5):

For those who are new, the easiest way is to go to **Terminal > Preferences > Global > Theme Varient** and change it to "default" which will change it to match with the rest of you applications theme.

Answer (score 3):

After a while of searching, I found out that you can do this with `dconf-editor`. Go to `/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/theme-variant` and change the value to either `'system'` or `'light'` (default = `'dark'`). Now you get a white terminal titlebar.

[image]